# Openshift: deploy minimized meanjs version

Tags: deployment, openshift, meanjs

I generated a meanjs app and build and minify it.
How should I deploy the prod build of app to openshift ?

Currently, I add all of the files to openshift repository and the push is pretty slow. I don't want to build my app on openshift. I can build it at local. I just want to deploy the final version on openshift.

Thank you
Green

Comment: I ssh to the gear and run rsync.
and what is running is "rsync" to copy the deployment.
I still don't understand : I just create one file but rsync takes a lot of time !!

Answer (score 0):

Dig into the source code of open shift. I found  these code

sync_runtime_repo_dir_to_deployment(deployment_datetime)          sync_runtime_dependencies_dir_to_deployment(deployment_datetime)       sync_runtime_build_dependencies_dir_to_deployment(deployment_datetime)

Those backup deployment for rollback later.
I don't like this. I have my own backup on my git. However, there is no way to set the number of backup to 0. The minimum is 1.

So the answer: I have to stay to with the slowliness.
Just wish that openshift allow me to set min backup deployment to 0